# Query String Query in Elasticsearch with - and *

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, full-text-search, sense

I have a problem with [Query String Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) in Elasticsearch. I write here a Sense code to replicate it.

```
POST myindex
POST myindex/mytype
    {
        "name":"t-shirt",
        "season": "2016-3"
    }
```

And I search:

```
POST myindex/_search
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
           "query": "2016-*",
           "fields": ["name", "season"]
        }
    }
}
```

Or:

```
POST myindex/_search
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
           "query": "t-shirt*"
        }
    }
}
```

These queries return no documents (but it should return the indexed document) and I don't know how to fix it.

I want to be generic as possible because this is an example, but my documents have a lot of field and the a user can search what he wants without limitations in the syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `"analyze_wildcard": true` (default is false) and I solved the problem of zero docs returned when I search with - and * in the same query.

Note: There is a different behavior between `"fields": ["_all"]` (or not specify) and specify all fields with their name (for example `"fields": ["name", "season"]`). In my most complete tests I tried it.

Answer (score 0):

The `name` field has been analyzed by the [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) and produced two tokens, i.e. `t` and `shirt` as you can see with the following `_analyze` query

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/test/_analyze?pretty -d 't-shirt'
{
  "tokens" : [ {
    "token" : "t",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 1,
    "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position" : 0
  }, {
    "token" : "shirt",
    "start_offset" : 2,
    "end_offset" : 7,
    "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position" : 1
  } ]
}
```

Instead you can search for `shirt*` and you'll get some results

```
POST myindex/_search
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
           "query": "shirt*"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know this well, but I cannot explain to the user to not search with "t" and "-"

Comment: Ok, then maybe you need to create a custom mapping for that field using the [whitespace analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-whitespace-analyzer.html) in order to tokenize your input at whitespaces and not dashes.

Comment: The problem is the same also with whitespace analyzer

Comment: Nope, with a whitespace analyzer, `t-shirt` gets tokenized as `t-shirt`. Try it out with `curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/test/_analyze?analyzer=whitespace&pretty' -d 't-shirt'`

Comment: Yes, but when you search with _t-shirt*_ there is the same problem. No documents are returned.

Comment: Provided you have deleted and recreated your index with the proper mapping, you also need to specify the whitespace analyzer in your query string query otherwise the search input is also tokenized with the standard analyzer.

Comment: You could also specify your query by naming the field you're searching, as in `"query": "name:t-shirt*"` so that's field's analyzer is used at search time.

Comment: I know that query string query (if not specified) uses the right analyzer for each field (specified during indexing). 
Your last solution is not what I want because the user can search without an explicit name field. I want to search with only _t-shirt*_ and this is not work also with a whitespace analyzer. Zero docs returned.

Comment: Ok, then in that case what you need is to use an [edge-n-gram tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html) in order to tokenize your input as `t`, `t-`, `t-s`, `t-sh`, `t-shi`, `t-shir`, `t-shirt`, etc and then when searching to use the [`keyword` analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-keyword-analyzer.html)

Comment: This is not the solution that I want. This is an example but I have a lot of field in my documents and I don't want to find a document with a n-gram. I want to be more generic as possible. I thought about removing the - first of give the query to ES, but for field as 2015-3 and searches as 2015-8 I don't want to remove -

Comment: I suggest you update your question and explain the precise use cases you need to support in a bit more details then. That will be more helpful to people trying to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Try [wildcard query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html)

```
POST myindex/_search
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "season": {
        "value": "2016-*"
      }
    }
  }
}
```